# How to change colour in custom menu in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have these two menus on google sheet, and I want to change their colour to red and blue. How can I do that?

```
function onOpen()
{
  var menuItems1 = [{name: "submit new order", functionName: "NewOrder"}];
  var menuItems2 = [{name: 'submit order change', functionName: 'OrderChange'}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("submit new order", menuItems1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("submit order change", menuItems2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to change a menu item color in apps script

Comment: so how can I highlight the menu, anyother way to do that?

Comment: @user3277721 yeah, you can tampermonkey it somehow. No way with native methods.